# Importing module: Exception has occurred: NameError name 'name' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, import

I'm new to python and i'm making a program to delete items older than 3 days in a specific folder. Now everything works fine, but i want to split up my file extensions to a module (so it's easier to add or delete extensions later) and import it into my main program.

Now i have following code:

extensions.py

```
extension = [".pdf",".csv",".xls",".xlsx",".txt",".DS_Store",".jpg",".png",".docx",".zip"]
```

Deleter.py

```
import extensions
for ext in extension:
    print(ext)
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write my program and it underlines the "extension" in my Deleter.py file.

I've been searching for hours now and tried everything (have an empty **init**.py file in the same folder, tried to work with subfolder,... but nothing works). I'm using Python 3.7
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Did you try `for ext in extensions.extension`?

Comment: You are my hero! Something so stupid blocked me for hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not creating any instance of extensions. So try this:

```
import extensions
for ext in extensions.extension:
    print(ext)
```